# MySQL fails to match string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `words` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`word` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
FULLTEXT KEY `word` (`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The following query returns all rows that contain the word 'person':

```
SELECT *  
FROM `words` 
WHERE `word` LIKE '%person%'
```

The following query returns nothing even though there is a row that only contains the word 'person':

```
SELECT *  
FROM `words` 
WHERE `word` = 'person'
```

Any clues? I'm confused.

Comment: Could there be some whitespace (leading or trailing) on that particular row?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't trailing spaces?  Get a count on the characters in that record...

Comment: `SELECT word, word = 'person' FROM `words` WHERE `word` LIKE '%person%'` - what would it return?

Comment: No spaces. Hold on, zerkms, I just notice the difference in the query. I'll check.

Comment: You don't see trailing spaces on normal output IIRC, so check zerkms's query if it has true on the row with "person".

Comment: Running zerkms query I get all 0's on the 2nd column, in other words no match. There are no spaces or any other weird char that I can find. I'm using phpMyAdmin for the testing but the straight php fails too.

Comment: Try `SELECT CONCAT('"', word, '"') FROM words...`

Comment: Well, Phil, it shows the closing " on the next line. On inspection the EOL disappears but it could be there still. I'll see if I can find it and remove it.

Comment: @Lara Try `UPDATE words SET word = TRIM(word)`

Comment: Darn! There was a CR! One hour banging my head against the table. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

A hidden character (13 = CR).

See very helpful strategy for finding these in the future in the comment above by Phil.

Comment: always sanitize your string inputs. Do trims etc. These type of problems can cause you to lose hair. Trust me on this one.